# View onDraw() delegate?

Tags: android

Is there something like a draw delegate for a View instance? I want to do a little bit of drawing for each view in my app. For example:

```
EditText et = ...;
et.addDrawDelegate(new DrawDelegate()) {
    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        // do some custom drawing here
    }
}
```

Normally I would just create a custom view class:

```
public class MyView extends SomeAndroidView {
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {}
}
```

but since I want to do this for many view types, this doesn't seem as easy as one global delegate.

Thanks

Comment: I would also like to know if something like this exists for a feature I would like to build